# Trouble getting result with this javascript using loops

Tags: javascript

Please help me with this. I was trying to select the 'li' item individually by looping through the list and when clicked change the color to green. If I just do it without a loop it selects entire list and changed the color to green instead of changing it individually, (which I don't want). Here is my HTML and javascript.

```js
function newItem(){
  var list = document.createElement('li');
  var input = document.getElementById('item').value;
  var text =document.createTextNode(input);
  list.appendChild(text);

  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(list);
  var list = document.querySelector('ul');
  for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    list.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        this.style.color='green';
      }
    })

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>My To Do List</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your list" id="item">
<button onclick ="newItem()">add</button>

<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: after adding the list. If I clicked on the individual list. It should change the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is going to the `.length` of the `<ul>` element (which isn't correct). You want to loop the `.length` of the amount of `li` elements.

So, instead of: `var list = document.querySelector('ul');`

It should be:   `var list = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');`

```js
function newItem(){
  var list = document.createElement('li');
  var input = document.getElementById('item').value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(input);
  list.appendChild(text);

  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(list); 
  
  // You don't want to loop to the length of the <ul>,
  // you want to loop to the length of the <li> collection
  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL > li');
  for(var i=0; i<listItems.length; i++){
    list.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        this.style.color='green';
      }
    })

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>My To Do List</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your list" id="item">
<button onclick ="newItem()">add</button>

<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

---

Now, that will make the code "work", but it's really incorrect, because every time a new item is added to the list, ***all*** the items get a new event handler added to them and that means that **the pre-existing items will get an additional handler registered that does the same thing as the existing handler**.

We can see this behavior by adding a simple `console.log()` to the handler and then adding 3 items and clicking on them. The first one will log a message just once, the second will log the message twice and the third one will log the message 3 times):

```js
function newItem(){
  var list = document.createElement('li');
  var input = document.getElementById('item').value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(input);
  list.appendChild(text);

  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(list); 
  
  // You don't want to loop to the length of the <ul>,
  // you want to loop to the length of the <li> collection
  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL > li');
  for(var i=0; i<listItems.length; i++){
    list.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        this.style.color='green';
        console.log("Green applied to element!");
      }
    })

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>My To Do List</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your list" id="item">
<button onclick ="newItem()">add</button>

<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

This is very wasteful. Instead, when elements are going to be created dynamically, we use **["event delegation"](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)** and set up the listener on a parent element that will exist right from the start and we leverage event bubbling to check where the event actually originated from when it occurs later.

Also, note the comments for other code improvements:

```js
// Get references to the elements you'll be using and do it just once
var btn = document.getElementById("add");
var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
var input = document.getElementById("item");

// Don't use inline HTML event attributes like onclick
btn.addEventListener("click", newItem);

function newItem(){
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = item.value;  // No need to create and append a text node
  ul.appendChild(listItem);
  
  item.value = "";  // Clear out the input
}

// Now, we'll set up a click event handler for the document.
// Any clicks inside the document (even on the new items created later)
// will bubble up and be intercepted by this event handler
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Check to see if the event originated at a list item
  if(event.target.nodeName === "LI"){
    // Change that element's color by appyling a pre-made CSS class.
    event.target.classList.add("item");
  }
});
```

```css
.item { color:green; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>My To Do List</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your list" id="item">
<button id="add">Add</button>

<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are targeting your list, you need to make an array of its children element using th `children` function.

```
  var list = document.querySelector('ul').children;
```

Then in your loop you can just target each of the children with you `i` var

```
list[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {...
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
function newItem(){
  var list = document.createElement('li');
  var input = document.getElementById('item').value;
  var text =document.createTextNode(input);
  list.appendChild(text);

  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(list);
  var list = document.querySelector('ul').children;
  for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    list[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        this.style.color='green';
      }
    })

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>My To Do List</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your list" id="item">
<button onclick ="newItem()">add</button>

<ul id="myUL">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The way you are trying to add event is not correct though.

Instead you can add an event listener on `document` and then check if this is the `tag==li` and do whatever you want to like

like

```
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        event.target.style.color='green';
      }
    })
```

And you don't event have to add a loop in this case. Just move this out of `newItem` function

```js
function newItem(){
  var list = document.createElement('li');
  var input = document.getElementById('item').value;
  var text =document.createTextNode(input);
  list.appendChild(text);

  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(list);
  var list = document.querySelector('ul');
}

    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        event.target.style.color='green';
      }
    })
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>My To Do List</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your list" id="item">
<button onclick ="newItem()">add</button>

<ul id="myUL">
```